# Mojarra: Serve non minified Javascript files

Tags: javascript, debugging, minify, mojarra

I have to debug part of the mojarra 2.1.3 javascript sources. Unfortunately, they are right now delivered in a minified version (jsf.js). I found jsf_uncompresses.js in the sources, how can I tell mojarra to use this? Do I have to replace jsf.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one better solution, add this snippet to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>   
<param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that the easiest way was to just dezip jsf-impl.jar provided by Glassfish 3.1, change jsf.js to jsf-uncompressed.js and then zip it again and rename it to .tar. Hope this could help somebody

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy uncompressed version of the .js file in your project and then include it in your page. This will override version insluded by JSF.